# Filtering a string

Tags: vb.net

I have some strings and I am wanting to see if they contain certain characters by using a filter.

The following is an example of the kind of thing that I am talking about...

```
Dim files() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles("folder path", filter)
```

Except, rather than getting files based on a filter, I am wanting to check a string via a filter. Where the filter can contain wildcards, required characters etc etc

Hopefully that makes sense...

Comment: So like, [`String.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx)?

Comment: Can you give us an example of the filter you want to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from RegularExpressions, VB.NET provides another - easy-to-use way:

The [**Like-Operator**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx)

```
Characters in pattern        Matches in string
          ?                  Any single character
          *                  Zero or more characters
          #                  Any single digit (0–9)
    [ charlist ]             Any single character in charlist
    [! charlist ]            Any single character not in charlist
```

[**How to: Match a String against a Pattern (Visual Basic)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te33kb6t.aspx)

Some examples from MSDN

Check for a seven-digit telephone number phoneNum for exactly three numeric digits, followed by a space, a hyphen (–), a period (.), or no character at all, followed by exactly four numeric digits:

```
Dim sMatch As Boolean = 
  (phoneNum Like "###[ -.]####") OrElse (phoneNum Like "#######")
```

Other patterns:

```
Dim testCheck As Boolean
' The following statement returns True (does "F" satisfy "F"?)
testCheck = "F" Like "F"
' The following statement returns False for Option Compare Binary
'    and True for Option Compare Text (does "F" satisfy "f"?)
testCheck = "F" Like "f"
' The following statement returns False (does "F" satisfy "FFF"?)
testCheck = "F" Like "FFF"
' The following statement returns True (does "aBBBa" have an "a" at the
'    beginning, an "a" at the end, and any number of characters in 
'    between?)
testCheck = "aBBBa" Like "a*a"
' The following statement returns True (does "F" occur in the set of
'    characters from "A" through "Z"?)
testCheck = "F" Like "[A-Z]"
' The following statement returns False (does "F" NOT occur in the 
'    set of characters from "A" through "Z"?)
testCheck = "F" Like "[!A-Z]"
' The following statement returns True (does "a2a" begin and end with
'    an "a" and have any single-digit number in between?)
testCheck = "a2a" Like "a#a"
' The following statement returns True (does "aM5b" begin with an "a",
'    followed by any character from the set "L" through "P", followed
'    by any single-digit number, and end with any character NOT in
'    the character set "c" through "e"?)
testCheck = "aM5b" Like "a[L-P]#[!c-e]"
' The following statement returns True (does "BAT123khg" begin with a
'    "B", followed by any single character, followed by a "T", and end
'    with zero or more characters of any type?)
testCheck = "BAT123khg" Like "B?T*"
' The following statement returns False (does "CAT123khg"?) begin with
'    a "B", followed by any single character, followed by a "T", and
'    end with zero or more characters of any type?)
testCheck = "CAT123khg" Like "B?T*"
```

I'm pretty sure that the LIKE-Operator under the hood is also [implemented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.compilerservices.likeoperator.aspx) as a subset of RegularExpression, but it's easier to use for simple requirements.

Here is a list of **differences** between LIKE-Operator and RegularExpressions:

**[Regular Expressions vs. the Like Operator (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235204.aspx)**

I Like it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with regular expression. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match.aspx

Comment: Some examples: '*.*', '*test.txt', '*te*.txt' - Where * is a wildcard.